# Cmus list playlists

Tags: command-line, music, cmus

I want to list all my playlists in cmus, but the playlist view only shows the contents of the current one.

Here is an issue on github for this feature: https://github.com/cmus/cmus/issues/431

According to this issue it had a working implementation, but I can't figure out how to toggle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out this is available in the newest version, which you can't get from apt. Seems like you have to build from source to use this feature for now.